# RXJava Vertx - Get route doesn't work

Tags: java, vert.x

I need create a get route for my API. 
This code :

```
final Router mainRouter = Router.router(vertx);
mainRouter.route("/ajax/*").handler(BodyHandler.create());
mainRouter.mountSubRouter("/ajax/", restAPI);
```

Next, implements restAPI :

```
restAPI.get("/t/:ID").handler(this::getTest);
restAPI.post("/connect").handler(this::connect);
restAPI.post("/validKey").handler(this::validKey);
```

The post request work, but, the get request doesn't work. 
I've "Not found" in the url /ajax/t/5 for exemple.

If we need more informations, say that!
Thanks,

Comment: This code looks good to me. Perhaps edit your question to include the full setup (including the code for testing)

Comment: At least share the snippet where you register the `Router` with `HttpServer`.